# Rename command doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, file, shell, rename, glob

I am using the 'rename' command to rename a set of files; for example:

```
    inputcac1010.inp.log  inputcac1110.inp.log  inputcac1210.inp.log  inputcac1310.inp.log
    inputcac1020.inp.log  inputcac1120.inp.log  inputcac1220.inp.log  inputcac1320.inp.log
    inputcac1030.inp.log  inputcac1130.inp.log  inputcac1230.inp.log  inputcac1330.inp.log
    inputcac1040.inp.log  inputcac1140.inp.log  inputcac1240.inp.log  inputcac1340.inp.log
    inputcac1050.inp.log  inputcac1150.inp.log  inputcac1250.inp.log  inputcac1350.inp.log
    inputcac1060.inp.log  inputcac1160.inp.log  inputcac1260.inp.log  inputcac1360.inp.log
    inputcac1070.inp.log  inputcac1170.inp.log  inputcac1270.inp.log  inputcac1370.inp.log
    inputcac1080.inp.log  inputcac1180.inp.log  inputcac1280.inp.log  inputcac1380.inp.log
    inputcac1090.inp.log  inputcac1190.inp.log  inputcac1290.inp.log  inputcac1390.inp.log
    inputcac1100.inp.log  inputcac1200.inp.log  inputcac1300.inp.log  inputcac1400.inp.log
```

must be renamed to

```
    inputcac1010.log  inputcac1110.log  inputcac1210.log  inputcac1310.log
    inputcac1020.log  inputcac1120.log  inputcac1220.log  inputcac1320.log
    inputcac1030.log  inputcac1130.log  inputcac1230.log  inputcac1330.log
    inputcac1040.log  inputcac1140.log  inputcac1240.log  inputcac1340.log
    inputcac1050.log  inputcac1150.log  inputcac1250.log  inputcac1350.log
    inputcac1060.log  inputcac1160.log  inputcac1260.log  inputcac1360.log
    inputcac1070.log  inputcac1170.log  inputcac1270.log  inputcac1370.log
    inputcac1080.log  inputcac1180.log  inputcac1280.log  inputcac1380.log
    inputcac1090.log  inputcac1190.log  inputcac1290.log  inputcac1390.log
    inputcac1100.log  inputcac1200.log  inputcac1300.log  inputcac1400.log
```

I used

```
rename 's/inp\.log/log/' *.inp.log
```

It doesn't seem to work. I renamed them in a different way by reading the file names and using sed, but I am quite confused as to why this command didn't work in my case!!! Could anyone clarify? Thanks!

Comment: YOur rename command works for me.

Comment: What about your command didn't work? Did it do anything? Without more information we certainly can't help you.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would be a better site for this question

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I am more curious as to why it didn't work, as it looks pretty trivial. Please have a look at the screenshot above!

Comment: What version of `rename` do you have? There are several different ones.

Comment: rename (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)

Comment: @Pradeep There are two major versions. One from `util-linux` one from `perl` related libraries. You're looking for the `perl` one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have the version of `rename` that takes arguments like this:

```
rename inp.log log *.inp.log
```

---

I usually just use a loop; performance isn't a big issue, because how often do you really need to rename lots of files at once?

```
for f in *.inp.log; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.inp.log}.log"
done
```

Comment: That solves the problem. Thanks! It is surprising that different versions work **very** differently, especially linux utilities!

Comment: They aren't different versions so much as two completely separate programs with the same name. There's no standard that either needs to conform to.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about investigating why does the rename tool not work in same cases.

Comment: There is no single 'rename' tool; as I said, there are two unrelated tools that do similar things that just happen to use the same name. If you don't realize which tool you are actually using and try to use it as the other one, it will likely fail. (If it *doesn't* fail, then it's due to the two programs behaving identically by coincidence rather than by design or conformance to a nonexistent specification.)